# Base change of n

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given some integer N, how many bases b are there such that the base-b representation of N starts with a 1?
ex:-
 6 has a leading digit 1 in bases 2, 4, 5 and 6: 610 = 1102 = 124 = 115 = 106.
 so fun(6)=4

Comment: [Code Chef December long challenge](https://www.codechef.com/DEC16/problems/BASE)

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**:-

A number x in base b starts with 1 if $b^n \le x < 2b^n$ for some $n\in \Bbb N$.
Therefore:- $$n\le\log_b{x}<n+\log_b2,n\ge 1$$
$$\implies  frac({\log_bx})<\log_b2 ,b\le x$$

AFAIK there is no closed form to find number of $b$ that satisfy these constraints, but a computer program can be written to check.

Answer (score 0):

The inequations written by Taraviya lead to
$$\{\log_b x\}<\log_b2$$
where $\{\cdot\}$ means the fractional part.

Still, I don't see a way to compute your function efficiently.

Nevertheless, for $x/2<b\le x$, $x$ has two digits in base $b$ and begins with $1$.